# asp.net System.Collections.Generic.List sort in array

Tags: asp.net

I already have a List dealers  and 
`strzipcode = Convert.ToString(dr["zero_to_50_miles"])` return a string:

```
94323,87883,43434,24343 ...
```

I am trying to sort all of Zip Codes from `dearlers` that have zipcode in strzipcode (94323,87883,43434,24343)
Example 
My dealer :

**"A","94323"**

**"B","87883**"

"C","12345"

"D","12345"

**"E","43434"**

"F","12345"

"G","12346"

**"H","24343"**

"I","12347"

So I expect my new dealer will be

**"A","94323"**

**"B","87883**"

**"E","43434"**

**"H","24343"**

```
using (var dr = db.ExecuteDataReader("GetZipCodes", CommandType.StoredProcedure, param))
{
    string strzipcode = "";

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        strzipcode = Convert.ToString(dr["zero_to_50_miles"]);
    }
    string[] zipcodes = strzipcode.Split(',');
    for (int a = 0; a < zipcodes.Length - 1; a++)
    {
        var cartr = (from i in dealers where i.Zipcode == strzipcode select i).ToList();
        dealers.Find(cartr);
    }
    var cartr = (from i in dealers where i.Zipcode == strzipcode select i).ToList();
}
```

What shoud I do?

Comment: here is my code

Comment: So, you want to sort items from `dearlers.zipcode` in the same order as `zipcodes` right? The question is a little bit unclear

Comment: Yes it is exactly what I want to do but there query of list<> item to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through dealer and find mismatches with strzip, then remove redundant items:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < dealer.Count; i++) {
             if (!strzipcode.Contains(dealer[i]))
             {
                 dealer.Remove(dealer[i]);
             }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq for filter specific number value.
For Ex.

```
var filteredFileSet = fileList.Where(item => filterList.Contains(item));
```

Comment: I try to do like this string 
                string[] zipcodes = strzipcode.Split(',');
                List<Dealer> filterList = new List<Dealer>();
                for (int x = 0; x < zipcodes.Length-1; x++)
                {
                    filterList.Add(new Dealer
                    {
                        Zipcode = zipcodes[x]
                    });
                }
                var filteredFileSet = dealers.Where(i => filterList.Contains(i));